# How to print the numbers for 0 to 10 in python and skip 5 and 8 between them

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to print a program using while loop in python numbers start from 0 to 10 but i want to skip 5 and 8 so the final result should be 0,1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10

```
i=0 
while i<=10 :
    print(i)
    if i==5 or i==8 :
        break
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

i have tried this code but not successfully working

Answer (score 0):

You will continue your while loop instead of break, therefore you can use `continue`:

```
i=0 
while i<=10 :
    if i==5 or i==8 :
        i += 1
        continue
    print(i)
    i+=1
```